# Use AWS cloudfront / S3 / Route53 to block all old .php webpages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-route53

I have just migrated a website. In the old website all of the pages ended in .php aka `www.<domain>.org/login.php`. The new website has bee created using react hosted in S3 with cloudfront. Google still displays all the old php pages, and I am only able to give a soft 404 error when an old page is visited.

How could I add in the tech stack I'm using a way of returning 404 errors for all the old .php pages. I ideally want to be able to use a rule as there are 100's of these old pages.

Comment: I'm confused, If all requests are now directed to a S3 bucket and it does not contain your previous php resources, it always returns 404, isn't it?
If your old php resources are cached in CloudFront, you can flush the cache, check the console.
Google will crawl your new website and will forget the old links.